# RewriteRule to nginx conf

Tags: nginx

I got an *.htaccess* with :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I need to convert this to nginx conf, it's very simple but I don't find..

I tried :

```
server {
    server_name ****;
    root /path;

    index index.html index.php;
    listen 80;

    # set expiration of assets to MAX for caching
    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location / {
      if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 break;
      }
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

But it downloads file instead of showing it. I don't get it ?

It works if I use :

```
http://example.com/index.php?url=login
```

But not with :

```
http://example.com/login
```

Comment: It may be not related to your problem, but with this config request `http://example.com/login` is rewrited to `http://example.com/index.php?url=/login`. Change `rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 break;` to `rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 break;` and test it.

Comment: If I do this, I have 404 error with `http://example.com/login`

Comment: Your config seems correct to me. Can you try `rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 redirect;`, run `curl -I http://example.com/login` and past the `Location` header content here?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it works using :

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri;
}
```